# Network Setup Problem

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, network-setup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I want to setup a connection between my robot and my laptop. I had done it successfully like a thousand times before but this time something went wrong and now, I am unable to locate the problem. Here are the details:

This is the error message:

> Unable to contact my own server at
> [http://192.168.10.200:59534/]. This
> usually means that the network is not
> configured properly.
>
> A common cause is that the machine
> cannot ping itself.  Please check for
> errors by running:
>
> ```
>     ping 192.168.10.200
> ```
>
> For more tips, please see
>
> ```
> http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup
> ```

IPs of the machines:

> IP of the robot: 192.168.10.200

> My IP:           192.168.10.199

On my laptop, exports are as follows:

> export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.10.200:11311

> export ROS_IP=192.168.10.200

Every ping combination works and also netcat tests are successful.

Furthermore, when I start both machines with this configurations and start roscore on my robot, I am able to see the topics on my laptop by typing

```
rostopic list
```

This means that the robot and my laptop can indeed communicate. However, when I try to run a node from the laptop I got the error message given above.

I performed an exhaustive search on almost all the combinations of ROS_xxx environment variables (which are related with network setup) and /etc/hosts file entries on both machines with no luck.

Hope someone guides me through these complicated configurations.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/115076/network-setup-problem/) by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 796 on 2014-01-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS_IP should be the IP address of the machine that it's set on, not the IP of the master.

Thus, on your laptop ROS_IP should be set to 192.168.0.199

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2014-01-07**:
I would never have noticed that. Thanks a lot.